# Omit keys/attributes/props from an array of objects using Ramda

Tags: javascript, node.js, ramda.js

I have an array as follows:

```
var arr = [
     {id: "a", val:1, val2: "i"}, 
     {id: "b", val: 2,  val2: "ii"}, 
     {id: "c", val:3,  val2: "iii"}
   ];
```

By using ramda I want to get an array as follows:

```
[{"id": "a"}, {"id": "b"}, {"id": "c"}]
```

So here I want to skip object attributes "val" & "val2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this by following approach:

```
 var result = R.map(R.omit(['val', 'val2']))(arr);
```

Or you can also write it as follows:

```
var fn = R.map(R.omit(['val', 'val2']));
var result = fn(arr);
```

Comment: `R.pick(['id'])` is another option if you only know the properties you want to keep rather than those you want to remove.

Comment: ... or perhaps `project (['id'])` , which folds in the `map` call as well.